# I can not adjust the edittext linespacing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, line

I want to adjust the line spacing of edittext.
I use a long line, and when I cross the line, linespacing is applied.
However, linespacing does not apply when I input Enter key.

[image]

Comment: can you add some code

Comment: I run into this problem, too

Comment: This is submitted as bug 3 years ago https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37009353 , and no one from Google care to fix this very obvious UI bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Library fixed the EditText linespacing issue  https://github.com/hanks-zyh/LineHeightEditText

[image]

Answer (score -3):

use this code for line space between two line

```
 android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
```

whole code is

```
      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp" //set the line space between 2 lines
            android:text="iadhadhsfbsfffbdgfddgdfdjkfhdjfhdkfhdfhdfhdkfhdkjhfkdhfdkhfdkfhdhfdkfhdkhfdjkfhdfhd"/>
```