# How to create a custom EditText layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

I want to create an EditText like  the Image below.

[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed2RZ.jpg)

This is my code (in the xml file of the layout):

```xml
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/newThoughtThoughtText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/lines"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/thought_first_text"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="15"
            android:textColor="@color/color_gray"   />
```

I have created a custom drawable layout file. But this only enables me to have one line at the end, and I need several lines inside the EditText.
How can I do this?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/color_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! You have to extend `EditText` and override `onDraw()` method. I also answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56212644/5823014

Comment: Thanks, i checked your answer and it helped. Btw, i managed to do what i wanted. Will just leave the topic here for further questions and to help others, in case.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to make changes in your drawable class which you have created.

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="-2dp"
    android:insetRight="-2dp"
    android:insetTop="-2dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
        <solid android:color="@color/md_grey_200" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

This will give you border bottom and you can change color according to your requirement.
If you don't want to give border to the each EditText you can add one View after each EditText like this.

```
                    <View
                    style="@style/MenuDivider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@color/black"/>
```

You can change the view height according and background to you.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem and to design the editText as wished.

This topic helped me:

[Android - How to make all lines in an edittext underlined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361755/android-how-to-make-all-lines-in-an-edittext-underlined)

I created my own custom EditText:

```
package com.example.appsiety.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.example.appsiety.R;

public class EditTextThought extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private Context context;

    public EditTextThought(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        initPaint();
    }

    public EditTextThought(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        initPaint();
    }

    public EditTextThought(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        initPaint();
    }

    private void initPaint() {
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_gray));
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int left = getLeft();
        int right = getRight();
        int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
        int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();
        int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
        int height = getHeight();
        int lineHeight = getLineHeight();
        int count = (height-paddingTop-paddingBottom) / lineHeight;

        for (int i = 0; i < count*2; i++) {
            int baseline = lineHeight * (i+1) + paddingTop;
            canvas.drawLine(left+paddingLeft, baseline, right-paddingRight, baseline, mPaint);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

and then in my layout file i used it:

```
<view
class="com.example.appsiety.utils.EditTextThought"
            android:id="@+id/newThoughtSituationText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_light"
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_gray"
            android:textColor="@color/color_gray"
            android:hint="@string/situation_first_text"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textVisiblePassword"
            />
```